# #limit_validation_errors submit problem

Tags: forms

I have a problem using #limit_validation_errors for a submit button on which I dont want all the validations to run. Here's my custom submit button :

```
$form['actions']['draft'] = array(
     '#type' => 'submit',
     '#value' => 'Save as draft',
     '#submit' => array(''),
     '#limit_validation_errors' => array(
       array('title'), // Validate $form_state['values']['title'].
     ),
);
```

It works perfectly in the sense that it checks the validation on the title field only, but the weird thing is, it does not submit any other field's values when submitted. I wrote a custom submit handler to check that. However, the values are present in `$form_state['input']` but not in `$form_state['values']`.

What I want simply is, this form will submit with just the values given and overlook the validations when this custom submit button is clicked.

FYI : I can get `$form_state['values']` perfectly in my custom validate function.

Any ideas? What am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 1):

It works as expected - in `$form_state['values']` you have **validated** values, and in `$form_state['input']` you have **raw** values. If you will limit validation to title field only - only this field will be transferred into "values" array.

Answer (score 0):

I had to switch from a `type="submit"` to `type="button"` in order to disable errors + use ajax.

```
  public function buildForm(array $form, FormStateInterface $form_state) {

    // ...

    // Create Draft Button
    $form['#prefix'] = '<div id="send-emails-manual-send-by-role-wrapper">';
    $form['#suffix'] = '</div>';
    $form['actions']['save_draft'] = [
      '#type' => 'button',
      '#value' => $this->t('Save Draft'),
      '#name' => 'submit__save_draft', // TODO: Make constant
      '#limit_validation_errors' => [],
      '#ajax' => [
        'callback' => [$this, 'ajaxSubmitForm'],
        'wrapper' => 'send-emails-manual-send-by-role-wrapper',
        'method' => 'replace',
        'effect' => 'fade',
      ],
    ];
    
    return $form;  
  }

  /**
   * Submit the form using ajax
   */
  public function ajaxSubmitForm(array &$form, FormStateInterface $form_state) {
    $this->submitForm($form, $form_state);
    return $form;
  }
```